# What does '-d' do in Unix?

Tags: unix

I have this code, it was set as a condition for a step.
what does the '-d' in the code mean?

```
if [ -d $FTBASEDIR/$1/$2 ]; then
    ftcmd="lcd $FTBASEDIR"
    ftcmd2="cd $FTROOTDIR"
    ftcmd3="put $1"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

It means: is the following argument a directory?

From the `bash` manpage (under `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`):

```
-d file
    True if file exists and is a directory.
```

There's a whole host of these, letting you discover regular files, character-special files, whether files are writable, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions:

> ```
> -d file
> ```
>
> True if *file* exists and is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

`[` is actually a command name, (nearly) equivalent to the `test` command.

Both `[` and `test` are implemented both as a built-in commands in many shells, and as actual executables, typically in `/usr/bin` (`[` is usually a symbolic link to `test`). (In the old days, they were just executables; building them into the shell lets tests be performed faster.)

The documentation for bash or for the `test` command explains that `-d` tests whether the following argument is a directory.

(I wrote "nearly" above; the difference is that `[` requires a matching `]` arguments, while `test` does not.)

Comment: what should I need test if a file exists?